# Fatal error: Call to undefined function file_exist() php

Tags: php

I have been checking whether a specific text file is existing using `file_exist()`, everything is written correctly and even the var_dump returns correct path but it always returns an error..

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function file_exist()
```

my code

```
$filepath = "C:/Users/t*******/workspacephp/".$track_id.".txt";
    var_dump($filepath);
    if (file_exist($filepath)){
    //do something
}else{
    //do something
}
```

Comment: Perhaps because the function is called [file_exists()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) (with an `s` on the end)

Comment: me too XD .....

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Functions is [file_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) you miss the last `s` in the function.